# Why are Play 2.2.3 test templates in a submodule not compiled?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

Tests in one of submodules in my multi-module project require separate test templates, which I put to `test/views/`. They are not getting compiled. How can I fix that?

I've looked into play sbt plugin sources (2.2.x branch) and the closest thing I've found is 
[PlaySettings.scala, line 111](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala#111)

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (state, unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile, sourceManaged in Compile, templatesTypes, templatesImport) map ScalaTemplates,
```

I guess, I need to add some setting like that to my own `build.sbt`.

**UPDATE**: the issue is resolved, see the answer below

Comment: If you could offer a sample project on github to clone and test locally, that would help. There are too many unknowns that I fear giving it a test without much help.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thank you for your reply! Here is a sample project. https://github.com/stys/play-223-test-templates Test temaplates fail to compile in the main project, so forget about the submodules. Run `play test` to see output of the test.

Answer (score 0):

It was close. The working solution is to add the following line to the project's `build.sbt`

```
sourceGenerators in Test <+= (state, unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test, sourceManaged in Test, templatesTypes, templatesImport) map ScalaTemplates
```